# A Database Error Occurred - Error Number: 1096 No tables used SELECT * WHERE 0 = 'fghr5' LIMIT 1

Tags: codeigniter

I want to insert the signup data into 'details' table of database.
Here is the code-

**Controller Code Part** (Controller Name- Login)

```
public function signup() {
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('first_name', 'First Name', 'required|alpha');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('last_name', 'Last Name', 'required|alpha');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('reg_mobile_mumber', 'Registered Mobile Number', 'required|numeric|exact_length[10]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|valid_email|is_unique[details.email]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|max_length[12]|is_unique');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('address', 'Address', 'required|max_length[100]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('state', 'State', 'required|alpha');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('city', 'City', 'required|alpha');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('pin_code', 'Pin Code', 'required|numeric|exact_length[10]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('business_name', 'Business Name', 'required|alpha_numeric_spaces');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('brand_name', 'Brand Name', 'required|alpha_numeric_spaces');
    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="text-danger">', '</div>');
    if ($this->form_validation->run()) {
        $post = $this->input->post();
        $this->load->model('User_model', 'user');
        if ($this->user->add_user($post)) {
            // echo "User Added";
            $this->session->set_flashdata('user', 'User added successfully');
            $this->session->set_flashdata('user_class', 'alert-success');
        } else {
            // echo "User Not Added";
            $this->session->set_flashdata('user', 'User not added Please try again!!');
            $this->session->set_flashdata('user_class', 'alert-danger');
        }

        return redirect('Login/signup');
    } else {
        $this->load->view('admin/signup');
    }
}
```

**Model Code Part** (Model Name- User_model)

```
public function add_user($array) {
    return $this->db->insert('details', $array);
}
```

And this is the error:

```
Error Number: 1096 No tables used SELECT * WHERE 0 = 'fghr5' LIMIT 1
```

Comment: your $post is not array $this->user->add_user($post).

Comment: print_r($post); what does it returns?

Comment: I tried with $post but the same error still persists, and when I opened inspect the error shown is- POST http://localhost/ciproj/Login/signup 500 (Internal Server Error). I searched about this error and it is related to ajax. I don't know ajax coding.

Comment: $post=$this->input->post(); print_r($post); what does it returns?

Comment: Same error-A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1096

No tables used

SELECT *

Comment: And same error in inspect- POST http://localhost/ciproj/Login/signup 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: It would appear that you are performing a SELECT in your Login code. Possibly in your Login Controllers signup method. Can you show the code for that please and the model being used? The code you have provided is clearly not related to your issue.

Answer (score 0):

remove `$post=$this->input->post();` with

```
$post=array(
'first_name' => $this->input->post('first_name'),
'last_name' => $this->input->post('last_name'),
'reg_mobile_mumber' => $this->input->post('reg_mobile_mumber'),
'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
'password' => $this->input->post('password'),
'address' => $this->input->post('address'),
'state' => $this->input->post('state'),
'city' => $this->input->post('city'),
'pin_code' => $this->input->post('pin_code'),
'business_name' => $this->input->post('business_name'),
'brand_name' => $this->input->post('brand_name')
);
```

Also make sure you have proper database connections and a table with proper structure named as "details"

Comment: "No tables used" problem solved. But in phpmyadmin the data is not updated. It is showing- MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). (Query took 0.0000 seconds.)

Comment: check this if it helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20927634/mysql-insert-mysql-returned-an-empty-result-set#:~:text=The%20result%20you%20get%20(%20MySQL,the%20query%20must%20run%20well.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|max_length[12]|is_unique')
```

To this

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|max_length[12]|is_unique[details.password]')
```

Or remove **is_unique** rule from set_rules function for password.

Reason is that when you apply is_unique rule for any field, you should mention from which database column it should check uniqueness

Comment: The "No tables used" error problem is solved but in phpmyadmin the data is not updated, it is showing- MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). (Query took 0.0000 seconds.)

Comment: remove **return** statement for a moment in ```add_user``` function and write ```echo $this->db->last_query();```. you will see insert query print there. copy the query and paste it in phpmyadmin. and then let me know what you see as result

Comment: also refresh table in phpmyadmin once your code executes.